# Database corrupted, can not drop

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database dict_development, inside which a table words.

I tried to delete words but no response for a long time, so I use ctrl+Z to interrupt the process. Then problem happens.

Now, I cannot do anything about dict_development, including:

```
drop database dict_development;

drop table words;

select * from words;
```

Each command leaves no response.

Meanwhile, other tables in dict_development is fine.

Now, I want to delete the table or database manually, for example, delete file in

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/mysql/data/dict_development
```

But I don't wether everything is done after deleting above file.

Anyone can give me a way to handle this?

============================== Updated =====================================

I restarted mysql server and now even mysql itself cannot run: no mysql.socket in generated in /tmp......

Answer (score 1):

ctrl-z suspends the process.  Probably not what you expected.

Type 'fg' to bring it back to the foreground.  Maybe it finished!

Comment: Sorry, but where to type 'fg'? BTW, I restarted my mysql server and now even mysql itself cannot run: no mysql.socket is generated in /tmp

Comment: 'fg' is the command-line command to bring suspended programs into the foreground (get it, f-g?).  Once you'vee rebooted your server, there's nothing left in the background, so it really doesn't matter.